# What is a Personal Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Personal Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Personal Words™ | Not Personal Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PUBLIC | PERSONAL |
| GOVERNMENT | BUREAUCRACY |
| LAYOUT | CHART |
| SHEPHERD | MARSHALL |
| ANSWER | FEEDBACK |
| MOUSETRAP | UNDERNEATH |
| CRIBBAGE | BLACKJACK |
| FUNDAMENTAL | NUCLEAR |
| THEREFORE | ERGO |
| SHELL | COVER |
| MUST | SHOULD |
| AWESOME | WONDERFUL |
| STILL | ANYMORE |

CSV version:

```
Personal Words™,Not Personal Words™
PUBLIC,PERSONAL
GOVERNMENT,BUREAUCRACY
LAYOUT,CHART
SHEPHERD,MARSHALL
ANSWER,FEEDBACK
MOUSETRAP,UNDERNEATH
CRIBBAGE,BLACKJACK
FUNDAMENTAL,NUCLEAR
THEREFORE,ERGO
SHELL,COVER
MUST,SHOULD
AWESOME,WONDERFUL
STILL,ANYMORE
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Personal Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Personal Words™, many more exist.

Comment: What an irony **PERSONAL** is not a *Personal word™* :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that Personal Words

> Contain personal pronouns in them

Examples

> PUBLIC $\rightarrow$ **I**, 
>  GOVERNMENT $\rightarrow$ **ME**, 
>  LAYOUT $\rightarrow$ **YOU**, 
>  SHEPHERD $\rightarrow$ **HER**, 
>  ANSWER $\rightarrow$ **WE**, 
>  MOUSETRAP $\rightarrow$ **US**, 
>  CRIBBAGE $\rightarrow$ **I**, 
>  FUNDAMENTAL $\rightarrow$ **ME**, 
>  THEREFORE $\rightarrow$ **HER**, 
>  SHELL $\rightarrow$ **HE**, 
>  MUST $\rightarrow$ **US**, 
>  AWESOME $\rightarrow$ **WE**, 
>  STILL $\rightarrow$ **I**

Comment: Quick and on the mark! +1

Comment: Damn, this is the first one I've managed to solve myself, but I was three hours late :P

Comment: Ooh that was fast! I guess the name of the words might have given it away a little bit :P